# WooCommerce: Move Coupon Field on Cart Page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to change the position of the coupon field on the cart page. I am vaguely familiar with actions and hooks, so I know I need to remove the woocommerce_cart_coupon action first and hook it to a different action, as in this example:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
```

My problem is, I don't know to from where to unhook this action. I cannot find a list of cart hooks and their hooked actions (like the **`content-single-product.php`** file) + order.

The coupon field should be placed after the "Proceed to Checkout" button. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hook **`woocommerce_cart_coupon`** doesn't hook the coupon php code itself and you will not be able to use it as in your example.

The related coupon php code (on cart page) is located on **`cart/cart.php`** template at line 132 to 150 and isn't hooked within a separate template. So You will have to edit **`cart/cart.php`** template, and this is not going to be so easy.

Here is the official related documentation for [**Overriding Templates via a Theme (Templates structure)**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: I figured it out by myself eventually. My problem was that, upon moving the coupon field somewhere else on the cart page, the "Apply coupon" button no longer worked. It was because it wasn't wrapped between the `<form></form>` tags. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @AlexP.  Ha yes all this kind of things have to stay inside `<form></form>` tags or can be outside if you add a hidden `<imput>` field (to emulate this field) and some jvascript/jQuery… but in this case is pretty complicate to make that works. Thanks, you are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your coupon PHP in a form tag with the correct form action.

```
<?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
 <div class="coupon">
  <form action="http://example.com/cart/" method="post">
   <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> 
   <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> 
   <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
   </form>
  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```